# Series with main focus being the time at 11:11:11

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I'm trying to remember a series/movie that I once watched when I was younger (several years ago (2000-2010 (I know, big span, but I can't pinpoint my memories better))). I never remembered the name of it as I only saw some small parts of it (been quite some years and my memory isn't built for long term storage).

I don't know much specifics about it, but this is what I remember of it.

- Small statues (toys?) come alive at 11:11:11.
- These statues are in animal form or represent animal/humanoids
- A child(?) got it from an old store.
- One of the small characters is a snake/snakelike and betrays (but in the end doesn't, I think) his 'friends/colleagues'.
- Of course there is some bad guy in there that wants those characters. The snake/snakelike person did aid him in an episode (or during the movie).

About the release date I can't tell much. It didn't seem a very old series/movies. I would guess it's made after 2000.

Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: I know it's not the correct answer, but for people who are interested, [Homestuck](http://homestuck.com) also features the time and date of 11/11 or 11:11:11 prominently as it was the date upon which the troll characters were first introduced.

Comment: @Mirzoda  - You say that statues or toys come alive at 11;11:11.  Therefore 11:11:11 comes during the course of the movie.  Is that November 11, 2011 or 11 hours, 11 minutes, and 11 seconds?  It seems probable that you mean it is the time of day, but if so you could have made it certain by saying whether it is 11:11:11 AM, 11:11:11 PM, both, or you don't know. Voyager had an episode "11:59", and I think that I remember a movie or TV movie with a time in the title and/or plot.

Comment: @M.A.Golding, Sorry if it wasn't clear. I'm a programmer by profession and by default the format for time is with : and dates are /. In the end it wasn't even 11h11m11s (See accepted answer). I just remembered several 11's but thought it was the time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is it possible this is the 2004 TV series, *[Shoebox Zoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoebox_Zoo)*?

[image: Logo for *Shoebox Zoo*]

> Shoebox Zoo mixes Scottish, Celtic, and later, Native American mythology. The first season is set primarily in Edinburgh and other historic locations, while the second season moves to Denver, Colorado, though the season was shot in Canada. The series' protagonist, Marnie McBride, an eleven-year old Scottish-American girl moves to Edinburgh with her father Ross following the unexpected death of her mother Rosemary. On her birthday, Marnie receives a shoebox containing four carved toy animals from a junk shop owner. Marnie discovers she can magically bring the toys to life, referred to collectively as the Shoebox Zoo. The four are in fact humans transformed into toys by their master, Michael Scot, an immortal alchemist and wizard, for stealing his magical codex, the Book of Forbidden Knowledge.
>
> In the series' backstory, Michael Scot lived in 12th century Scotland, where he crafted the Book of Forbidden Knowledge, containing his scholary work on alchemy and magic. However, the book contained black magic forged from Michael's pride and ambition. He created the series' antagonist, Juan Roberto Montoya de Toledo, a shapeshifting homunculus, using the book's magic. However, Toledo was rejected by Michael, inspiring him to seize the book's power and conquer the world. Michael's four students - Edwin, Bruno, Ailsa, and his own son Wolfgang - steal the book to hide it from Toledo, though Wolfang takes it out of spite towards his negligent father. The book is lost, Michael transforming the four into toys and putting them to sleep until a prophesied Chosen One, identified as Marnie, possesses magic to awaken them and find the book.

One of the toys is indeed snake-based:

> The Shoebox Zoo themselves are four computer-generated Celtic toy animals, actually Michael's students transformed into toys for stealing the book. The voice actors recorded their lines in a London studio before filming for the television series began. Edwin (Rik Mayall), a silver eagle dressed like a knight acts as the self-appointed leader, but he is pompous, vain, hypocritical and cowardly. His name and inability to fly is a nod to British Olympic skier Eddie "The Eagle" Edwards. Bruno (Alan Cumming) is a kindhearted but bumbling, dim-witted bear made of stone and fascinated by the modern world in counterbalance to the others' fear of it. **Ailsa (Siobhan Redmond), a cynical, distrusting golden adder is the sole female of the group who has little faith in others**. The fourth member is Wolfgang (Simon Callow), a wily and deceitful blue-and-golden wolf made of wood, is Michael's bitter son, and joins forces with Toledo during the first season.

From the intro for the first episode, your elevens:

> In every generation dawns a most auspicious day, the day when four elevens meet, and sleepers have their say. The day to which the fickle sands of time and tide have run. The day when fate and prophecy, reveal the chosen one. 
>   Marnie McBride was 11 years old, that's to say at precisely 11:00 that
>   evening the eleventh day of the eleventh month she would be 11 years old.

My final search terms which found it was *tv film animal statues come to life at 11:11* after several abortive attempts at looking for "11:11:11", which largely points to a few horror films using that as a date.

You can find episodes on Youtube, but I haven't found anything official.

Comment: Yes!! Thanks, this was indeed it! I knew it was something with 11, but I must have mistook the 11 day, 11 month, 11 hour, … as the actual hours, minutes and seconds. Thanks again!